# rustの構造体について

Tags: rust

以下の例で関数set_enableを実行した後、enabledがtrueになっているかどうかを確かめたいのですが
main関数内でenabledを呼び出すにはどうすればいいのでしょうか

```
struct Gpio{
    enabled:bool,
    direction:bool,
    output:bool,
    //periph:GPIO_CONFIG,
}

impl Gpio{
    pub fn set_enable(&mut self){
        self.enabled=true;
    }

    pub fn set_direction(&mut self){
        if self.enabled!=true{
            return;
        }
        self.direction=true;
    }

    pub fn set_output_status(&mut self){
        if self.enabled!=true{
            return;
        }
        if self.direction!=true{
            return;
        }
        self.output=true;
    }
}

fn main(){
    let mut pin=Gpio{
        enabled:false,
        direction:false,
        output:false,
    };
    
    println!
}
```

Comment: おそらくTeratailのこの質問 https://teratail.com/questions/371484
 の続きだと思いますが、もし解決したのなら、その質問を解決済みにしてください。

あと、以前、私がここ（Stack Overflow）で別の質問に回答したとき、その回答が質問ごと削除されてしまいました。（お礼のメッセージは読みました）　そのため、それ以来、あなたからの質問に回答することを躊躇しています。

こちらにも書かれているように、できるだけ質問は削除しないようにしてください。よろしくお願いします。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

「もしあなたの質問に良い回答がついている場合、それらの回答ごと削除してしまうのは公平ではありません。他のユーザーがあなたを助けるために労力を割いたわけですし、もうあなたには必要ない回答だとしても、他のユーザーには必要かも知れません」

Comment: そういう決まりがあったとは知りませんでした。今後は気を付けます申し訳ありません

Answer (score 2):

そのまま呼び出してみたところ、問題なく出力されました。

```rust
fn main(){
    let mut pin=Gpio{
        enabled:false,
        direction:false,
        output:false,
    };
    
    if pin.enabled {
        print!("pin.enabled is true");
    } else {
        print!("pin.enabled is false");
    }
}
```

Comment: 別の方法で解決した場合は、自己回答として回答を載せて、チェックマークを付けると、この質問は解決済みとなります。